# XSL: How to transform XML into PDF whilst preserving formats from HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, apache-fop

I have the following HTML code:

```
<b>My Formatting</b>
<br>
<ol>MY List
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2 & 2.1</li>
</ol>
```

What I would like to achieve after FOP transformation is the following:

**MY Formatting**
My List

1. item 1
2. Item 2 & 3

I have an XSL configured as the following:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p">
 <fo:block>
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="b">
 <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
</fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

Will this work? I am a novice with XSL and Transformation, so any guidance will be appreciated. All I want is to make sure that any HTML-markup tags (e.g. bold, italic, big, strong, etc.) and special signs (e.g. &) are transformed correctly. I tried to find other answers in SO, tried using `copy-of` and `select` but didn't get my solution. Also, this has to be generic as I want to create the XSL such that if no markup exists, everything will work normally. Another way of expressing my question is "How do I generalise all the `<b>,<p>,<u>` etc. HTML-markup tags in my XSL stylesheet such that it is replaced by a specific font-weight, font-size, etc. after transformation?"

Any ideas?

Comment: have you noticed this one : https://code.google.com/archive/p/flying-saucer/ ?

Comment: @Bax            using another library is not an option for me unforunately. I am trying to use what I have. A good source though, thanks!